# c programming language fixed size array

Tags: c

If I declare a function parameter as myfunc(char (*p) [10]) what is the
correct syntax for returning said pointer p ?

```
char *myfunc(char (*p) [10]) {
    /* do something */
    return (*p);
}
```

compiles and appears to work but it doesn't look correct (i.e., it doesn't
seem to suggest that the pointer returned necessarily is a pointer to an
array of size 10).

Comment: Your question does not make sense. You say you want the function `myfunc` to simply return its function argument, but this would only make sense if the argument and the return value were of the same type. Are you asking how to cast a pointer from `char (*)[10]` to `char *`?

Comment: No. I would like to know the correct function definition to imply that the function returns a pointer to an array of size 10. The example I gave works but does not make it clear that the pointer returned is to an array of size 10. In short, I do not know how to define the return type of the function to reflect this.

Comment: First of all, you need to decide whether you are returning `p` or `*p` since those are two very different things. `*p` is in fact a `char *`, so your function is correct as is.

Comment: See above comment.

Comment: `char (*myfunc(char (*p)[10]))[10]` is a function that takes a pointer-to-an-array and returns a pointer-to-an-array. The absolutely horrible syntax is the reason that you won't often see this. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is either a very [academic question](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/academic_question) or it is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). My guess is it is the latter.

Comment: user3386109  would this then be the correct form:                                     int (*func(int (*p) [10])) [10] {
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  (*p) [i] = i;
 return p;
}
for example ?

Comment: @raymond I would never write code like that, even though it *is* syntactically correct. It's not clear what you hope to accomplish by doing that.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was told that a definition such as myfunc(char (*p) [10]) was the most proficient way to pass around a fixed size array in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char x` declares a character.

`char x[10]` declares an array of ten characters.

`char (*x)[10]` declares a pointer to an array of ten characters.

`char (*x())[10]` declares a function that returns a pointer to an array of ten characters.

`char (*x(char (*p)[10]))[10]` declares a function that takes a pointer to an array of ten characters and returns a pointer to an array of ten characters.

Comment: with typedef a bit more clear:  `typedef char (* ptr_to_char_arr_10) [10]; ptr_to_char_arr_10 (*f_returning_arr_p)(void) ;  ptr_to_char_arr_10 (*f_receiving_and_returning_arr_p)(ptr_to_char_arr_10) ;`

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` is one of your friends. Declare the type alias pointer to your required array:

```
typedef char (* ptr_to_char_arr_10) [10];
```

Now use it for `myfunc`:

```
 ptr_to_char_arr_10  myfunc(ptr_to_char_arr_10 p) {
    /* do something */
     *p[0] = 42;
    return p;
}
```

And now use it to use `myfunc`:

```
int main ( void )
{
    char char_arr_10 [10] = {0};

    ptr_to_char_arr_10 arrp = myfunc(&char_arr_10) ;

    assert( *arrp[0] == 42 );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mf96Wboan)

Pointer to the array is a powerful concept. For further inspiration perhaps [see it here](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dont-use-fake-matrices/), used with Variably Modified Types and heap allocation.

### Bonus

The question is actually titled: "c programming language fixed-size array". Arrays as function argument actually can be declared with a "fixed" size.

```
// "fixed " array argument declaration
static void  dbj_assign(
        char val_, 
        // run time size of the array arg.
        const int count_, 
        // array argument of a minimal required size
        char char_arr [static count_]
     ) 
    {
        /* char_arr can not be null here*/
        /* do something */
        char_arr[0] = val_;
    }
```

That `char_arr` argument is also a Variably Modified Type (VMT), with minimal size required also declared. Usage is in the same [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mf96Wboan).